# PHP Session only saves last item

Tags: php, mysql, session

In follow up on this question: [Save database row id in session for use later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634434/save-database-row-id-in-session-for-use-later)

I'm now running into the following problem. The session is now (thankfully) stored. And the next page's content is filled dynamically. But ALL pages have the same `database id` and not the id that is specific for that link/item.

I read something about the fact that I'm over writing the session ID's again and again. And I need to store the session in an Array.

So what I did was the following, I changed this:

```
$identi = $row['Id'];
$_SESSION["product_id"] = $identi;
```

Into this:

```
$identi = $row['Id'];
if(!is_array($_SESSION['product_id'])) {
        $_SESSION['product_id']=array();
    }
        $_SESSION['product_id']=$row['Id'];;
```

But this still only stores the ID of the last item in the session an not the individual items. So I can have each item link with a specific ID.

For good measure my SQL Query:

```
<?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM assortiment WHERE Categorie = '$productid' ORDER BY Id DESC ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<a href='/dbtest/dinner/amsterdam/".$row["Slug"]. "/" . $row["Id"] . "'><div class='products'><div class='col-sm-3'><div class='product-img'>";
        $identi = $row['Id'];
        if(!is_array($_SESSION['product_id'])) {
            $_SESSION['product_id'] = array();
            }
            $_SESSION['product_id'] = $row['Id'];;

        echo "<img src='http://www.example.nl/Uploaded_files/Thumbs/" .$row['Fotomateriaal']. ".jpg'>";
        echo "</div></div><div class='col-sm-6'>";
        echo "<div class='h2-container'><h2>" . $row["Product"]. "</h2></div>" .  $row["Samenvatting"]. "";
        echo "</div><div class='col-sm-3'><div class='col-sm-12 text-right'>
                    <div class='border'>
                        <p style='margin-bottom:20px;width:30px;'><i class='fa fa-heart' aria-hidden='true'></i></p>
                    </div>
                </div>";
        echo "<table>
                <tr>
                    <td><i class='fa fa-users' aria-hidden='true'></i></td>
                    <td><p>vanaf 10 personen</p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><i class='fa fa-clock-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></td>
                    <td>" . $row["Tijdsduur"] .  " uur</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><i class='fa fa-euro' aria-hidden='true'></i></td>
                    <td>vanaf " . $row["VerkoopPP40"] ." p.p. <small>excl btw</small></td>
                </tr>
            </table></div></div></a>";

    if(isset($_SESSION['product_id'])){
    echo $_SESSION['product_id'];
    };

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}?>
```

Can anybody help me out with this one? As always thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add new items to an array you do it like this :

```
$_SESSION['product_id'][] = $row['Id'];
```

What you did is only overwrite the value of the `product_id` in your `$_SESSION` array.

EDIT:

Please take a look at this [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: If I use your code. And echo it, It only returns `array`?

Comment: Yes, because it is an array.

Comment: But should it show the Id's for the items... I know what arrays are.

Comment: try to `var_dump()` the array, to see the values.

Comment: A var_dump give me the following values: `array(1) {  [0]=>  string(4) "9709"}`, `array(1) {  [0]=>  string(4) "9708"}` and so on. It gives me the correct Ids.

Comment: i am glad that i helped out.

Comment: So, how to continue? The array is correct right? But Nothing the Id's are not stored in the session only the word `array`

Comment: this is not in the scope of your question. I don't know what you want to achieve